# Need JQuery retro engineering assistance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, blackberry

I have the following code

```
function dbFaultgo() {

        var f = element('faultForm');
        var headcode = f.elements['headcode'].value;
        var location = f.elements['location'].value;
        var detail = f.elements['detail'].value;
        var image = f.elements['image'].value;
        var fullname = f.elements['fullname'].value;
        var mobilenumber = f.elements['mobilenumber'].value;
        $('#loadingmessage').show();  // show the loading message.
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://(url removed)/save.php',
            data: { 
                headcode:headcode,
                location:location,
                injuryreport:detail,
                image:image,
                fullname:fullname,
                mobilenumber:mobilenumber
            },
            //change the url for your project
            success: function(data){
                $('#loadingmessage').hide();  // hide the loading message.
                alert('Your comment was successfully added');
                changePage ('page_05.html?v=1')

            },
            error: function(){
                $('#loadingmessage').hide();  // hide the loading message.
                alert('There was an error adding your comment');
            }
        });

        return false;
```

};

which is perfectly suitable for almost every smart phone... except one I need it work on Blackberry Bold running OS5 which does NOT allow Ajax as it is not compatible.

Is there an older Javascript format compatible with OS5 blackberryies (think HTML4, IE8) of the above functions or will I need to use some kind of thirdparty javascript plugin?

Comment: Jquery is cross-browser compatible so if that code don't work on BB i'm pretty sure it will never work. I suggest to detect user agent and use a normal post instead on BB. So you won't lose the magic of ajax, and your code will work on all platform.

Comment: Works on blackberry OS6 onwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Ajax, perhaps use a traditional HTML form and a POST that takes the user to a "your comment was added" page? Depending on your application it would result in a minor degradation of user experience.

Comment: I was planning to go down the route of this, but want to keep the BB5 user experience the same as the BB6 / BB7 so we can keep the docs pretty similar.

If I post to the server using the PHP script with an action="(url)/save.php" (posts to MYSQL) then how do I direct the experience back into the app from the server end?

With AJAX I just get a clear success or fail with no special coding at the server side and all is sweet.

or can I add something at the server side, or client side that a success will go to the thank you page (defined as page_05.html)

Comment: Ok now posting to my remoter server using a standard post as suggested..  However I am not able to return to the app as REMOTE_HOST does not come back the phone, just errors on the server.. And HTTP_REFERRER comes back to the form..

Comment: I don't know what is or isn't possible with BB5, but you could use Javascript to display the hourglass then have your form post in a hidden iframe with a javascript return result (perhaps a JS callback to the main page), when the post finishes (either with a success or a 500 error!) your parent page can use this to determine whether to display a success or fail message to the user.